# erase map element using an iterator inside a function

Tags: c++, c++11

I need to erase map elements using an iterator inside a function which takes map iterator as argument, but getting runtime error(free(): double free detected). This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

std::map<int32_t, int32_t> mapp;

void erasee(std::map<int32_t, int32_t>::iterator itr) {
    itr = mapp.erase(itr);
}

int main()
{
    mapp.emplace(1, 1000);
    
    std::map<int32_t, int32_t>::iterator itr = mapp.begin();
    while(itr != mapp.end()) {
        std::cout << "before" << std::endl;
        
        erasee(itr);
        
        std::cout << "after" << std::endl;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where are you moving the iterator to the next element? add `itr++` at the end of the while loop.

Comment: @Tony inside `erasee` function since `std::map::erase` returns iterator to next element. I am thinking iterator is passed by reference to `erasee` function, is that correct?

Comment: No it is not. Either add `&` to itr in function declaration, or `itr++` at the end of the while loop.

Comment: @Tony is it like I have to pass a double pointer like `int**` in order to modify the pointer variable `int*`?

Comment: No. The only exception I know is a raw array which decays to pointer. In your case, the iterator is sent by value, not by reference. This is why `&` is needed or incrementing it in main...

Comment: No point in doing a function that only erase the item from the map. Replace ` erasee(itr);` in your `main()`function code by `itr = mapp.erase(itr);` and delete `erasee`  function. In that case, adding an extra function make the code harder to understand.

Answer (score 1):

`itr` is passed to `erasee` by value. Consequently reassigning it has no effect after `erasee` returns.

As a quick fix you can pass it by reference:

```
void erasee(std::map<int32_t, int32_t>::iterator & itr) {
```

Though returning a new iterator might be a more readable solution.

Comment: `[[nodiscard]] auto erasee(std::map<int32_t, int32_t>::iterator itr) { return mapp.erase(it); }`